# Apple menu stops working

Tags: keyboard

Mac OS 10.12.3 Seemingly at random, certain functions stop working. Notifications (top right) are transparent, volume control from keyboard stops working but particularly the Apple Menu top left stops working so I can not shut down or anything else - force quit, about this Mac etc. Switch off using power button and all fine when switch on. Have look for conflict between pros but nothing consistent. Any suggestions please?